# Display join date and last_login in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have User default Django User model to register user. I want to print user last_login and join_date on the template. And also I want to check if user is active or not.

I want to check user active status like this, If user is currently using my website the status should be "Active" If User logged out Then status should be "Loged out"
if it is possible please provide me solution for this as well

accounts/models.py

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, default="1", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default="default/user.png")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} profile'
```

dashboard/views.py (to display user data)

```py
def admin_home(request):
    data = Profile.objects.filter(Q(user__is_superuser=False), Q(
        user__is_staff=False)).order_by('-user__last_login')[:10]
    context = {
        'data': data,
    }
    return render(request, "instructor/admin_home.html", context)
```

Accounts/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
app_name="accounts"
urlpatterns=[
    path('register',views.register,name="register"),
    path('admin_login',views.admin_login,name="admin_login"),

    path('user_login',views.user_login,name="user_login"),

    path('admin_editprofile',views.admin_editprofile, name="admin_editprofile"),
    path('user_editprofile',views.user_editprofile, name="user_editprofile"),
    path('admin_profile',views.admin_profile, name="admin_profile"),
    path('user_profile',views.user_profile, name="user_profile"),
    path('Logout',views.Logout, name="Logout"),
    path('user_chage_password' , views.user_chage_password , name="user_chage_password"),
    path('admin_change_password',views.admin_change_password,name="admin_change_password"),

]
```

Extra I have two apps one is the dashboard and other accounts. In the accounts app I am implementing only accounts' related URLs and in the dashboard app I am using it for other things.

For user registration, I am using the Django's default `User` model.

show_all_users.html or template file (for displaying user's data)

```html
    <html lang="en" class="no-focus">
    <head>
      {% load static %}

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" id="css-main" href="{% static 'css1/codebase.min.css' %}">

    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="page-container" class="sidebar-o sidebar-inverse side-scroll page-header-fixed main-content-narrow">
           
         {% include "instructor/sidebar.html" %}

              {% include "instructor/admin_nav.html" %}

            <!-- Main Container -->
            <main id="main-container" style="background-color:white;">
                <!-- Page Content -->
                <div class="content">
             

    <div class=" container  mt-5" style=" position: absolute; margin-left:-4%;">
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-success text-center"></h1>
            <h4 class="text-center text-danger">Recently Logged in users</h4>
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100% color:gray;" >

    <thead style="background-color : #607d8b;">
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Profile</th><th scope="col">Username</th>
        <th scope="col">Last_login</th>
        <th scope="col">join_date</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for userData in data %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{userData.id}}</th>
        <td><img style="width: 40px; border-radius:15px;" src="{{userData.image.url}}" alt="this is it."></td>
        <td>{{userData.user.username}}</td>
        <td> {{request.user.profile.date_joined }}</td>
        <td>{{ request.user.profile.last_login }} </td>
        

        <td>

        <a href="{% url 'dashboard:delete_user' userData.id %}"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="window.mytest()">Delete</button></a>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.mytest = function() { var isValid = confirm('Are you sure to Delete this user?');
        if (!isValid) { event.preventDefault();  alert("It wont delete. Yay!");}}</script>
            
        </td>
        
    </tr>
    {% endfor %} </tbody></table></div>
    </div>
    </main>
    {% endblock body %}
```

But this `<td> {{request.user.profile.date_joined }}</td>` line prints login date of currently logged in user but I want to show all user's `last_login` date.

And this `<td>{{ request.user.profile.last_login }} </td>` line prints nothing.

Comment: Answer as suggested by  @enes Islam for creating signals.py file. I already have signals.py file and I put suggested code   in my alreary existing signals.py file

Comment: No @Sunderam Dubey  Now I to just print all users last_login and date_joined only

Comment: No I just want to print last_login date and time like May 22, 2022, 6:23 p.m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter those users which have logged in at least one time through `Q(user__last_login__isnull=False)`.

Try this query in the view:

views.py

```py
def admin_home(request):
    data = Profile.objects.filter(Q(user__is_superuser=False), Q(
        user__is_staff=False), Q(user__last_login__isnull=False)).order_by('-user__last_login')[:10]
    context = {
        'data': data,
    }
    return render(request, "instructor/admin_home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

create `signals.py` and add this snippet:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in,user_logged_out
from datetime import datetime

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged(sender,request,user,**kwargs):
    user.profile.last_login = datetime.now()
    user.profile.save()
```

add the `related_name` attribute to your user field below your **Profile** model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,default="1", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")   
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="default/user.png")
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.date_joined = datetime.now()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} profile'
```

run on terminal:

```
python manage.py makemigrations    

python manage.py migrate
```

[the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login)

Comment: Thank you @enes Islam. I am new in Django I don't comfortable with Django documentation, can you please provide me better solution fir my problem it will be very helpful for me

Comment: what should I use to display all information on template

Comment: please provide some information about template to print `last_login`  `join_date` and `active status`

Comment: you can use {{ request.user.profile.date_joined }}  {{ request.user.profile.last_login }}

Comment: Thanks you for your precious time @enes islam but it `{{ request.user.profile.date_joined }} ` prints last_login data and ` {{ request.user.profile.last_login }} ` prints nothing. one more issue is,  This `{{ request.user.profile.date_joined }}` code prints same date for all user but I want to display all users last_login and join_date

Answer (score 0):

### Issue:

Only `last_login` and `date_joined` are the valid fields in default `User` model of django.

Don't use `request.user.....`, since it prints the details of current logged in users, as you stated that I want it to display for all users.

> `Question 1:` But this `<td> {{request.user.profile.date_joined }}</td>` line prints login date of currently logged in user but I want to show all user's last_login date.

> `Answer:` This is because `request...` give you current logged in user's details not all users' details.

> `Question 2:` And this `<td>{{ request.user.profile.last_login }} </td>` line prints nothing.

> `Answer:` It is because, there is wrong relationship of models.

---

---

### Solution:

Try below code in template file for displaying all users:

```html
<td> {{userData.user.last_login }}</td>
<td>{{ userData.user.date_joined }} </td>
```

Instead of this code you've tried:

```html
<td> {{request.user.profile.date_joined }}</td>
<td>{{ request.user.profile.last_login }} </td>
```

> `Remember:` Here, you have filtered only those users which are not staff as well as superuser, so these users are normal users. And if `last_login` column prints `None` that means the user has not logged even single time. And for `date_joined`,by default current time is taken by django. And if you see another time than your local machine that means you haven't set time zone in `TIME_ZONE` in `settings.py`. The timezone for India is `Asia/kolkata`, for more info refer [`Time zones`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/)<sup>[django-doc]</sup>.

Comment: should I have to use the code suggested by @enes Islam in signals.py and model.py or I can use `<td> {{userData.user.last_login }}</td>
<td>{{ userData.user.date_joined }} </td>` directly without making changes in exixting signals.py and model.py

Comment: One more thing, the user who have not login yet it shows none in the last_login column. And show  users who have't loged in as well but I want to show only those users details who have logged in recently. Is there a way to filter users if yes please help me

Comment: @Ajay you mean only those users you want to show who have logged at least one time, so that it does not show `None`?

Comment: I want to show recent login of a month

Comment: Yes @ sunderam Dubey something like that

Comment: @ sunderam Dubey Now I want to filter only those user who were login at least one time. My plan is I filter only those users who have login atleast one time and after filtering I will show only 10 entry to admin (the entry will be only those users who have loggin recently)